# Trying to access buttons inside of a asp.net repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
   <div class="row">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrProducts_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 ">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="background-color:white; width:100%;">
                        <img src="images/<%# Eval("image")%>" class=" img" style="width:300px; height:300px;" />
                        <div class="caption">

                            <div class="hidden">Title: <%#Eval("productsID")%></div>
                            <div class="ProductName">Title: <%#Eval("name")%></div>
                            <div class="ProductPrice">Price: £<%# Eval("price")%></div>  
                            <asp:Button ID="addItem" CommandName="addItem" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("productsID")%>' CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Add" OnClick="addItem_Click" />             
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater> 
    </div>
```

How would i go about gaining control to my button in aspx file, i would like to change to visibility of the button to true only when the session is created.

Comment: Can you expand on what "session is created" means? That can substantially affect the answer

Comment: so when a user logs in with valid credentials, a session is created, i want to use that session to then toggle the button visibility based on whether the session is null or not.

Comment: Why not just send it through Viewbag and check it in the view as if (ViewBag.IsAuthorized)

Comment: Session in asp.net web sense is always created, no matter if user is authenticated. Are you really looking to check if user is logged in?

Comment: @let_the_coding_begin, this is not asp.net mvc, no ViewBag

Comment: @let_the_coding_begin he wrote about Repeater: it's not MVC

Comment: well i'm really looking to whether the session is null or not but that isnt the issue im facing, the issue is that i cant access my fields because it is inside of a repeater, if i take the button out side of the repeaters scope i can gain access.

Comment: I'm not sure but what do you have as the value of      @Request.LogonUserIdentity or @User.Identity? Maybe use that as your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have ***ItemDataBound*** event, you could easily retrieve *addItem* inside the event and set it visible value.

```
protected void rptrProducts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var addItem = e.Item.FindControl("addItem") as Button;
        addItem.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["SomeValue"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to use ***ItemDataBound*** event, if you want to manipulate individual row inside Repeater.

Comment: thanks this solved my error but i had to change the code this

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `Visible` property of the button:

1. Directly when data are databound (aspx or code behind in `ItemDataBound` event)

   ```
   <asp:Button ... Visible='<%# IsLogged() %>' />
   ```

   and in code behind:

   ```
   protected bool IsLogged()
   {
        return Session != null && Convert.ToBool(Session["IsLogged"]);
   }
   ```

Comment: do i add the prerender to the repeater or the button?